# Trouble in XML parsing

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file of the structure as follows:

```
<article>
<body>
text1
<collectionlink>
text2
</collectionlink>
text3
</body>
</article>
```

i have printed `text3` using node.tail of elementtree.how can i find parent of `text3` i.e `body` here. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can try it using: element.xpath('..').
This should select the parent element.

You can have a closer look here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html